# laravel not redirecting to home after login

Tags: php, laravel

i'm facing a problem in laravel with logging users in, i can log in users correctly however the problem is that after a user logins in he is redirected to the login POST method instead of home i've set the `redirectTo` path to /home but it still doesn't work.  and in the`RedirectIfAuthenticated` class i've set it to redirect to home but still doesn't work i have no idea what is causing this problem... my code for logging users in:

```
 public function login(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;
    //If the user checked the remember me checkbox then make sure to remember him
    if(isset($request->rememberMe)) {
        if (\Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], true)) {
            $user = User::findOrFail($email);
            //Remember the user
            \Auth::login($user, true);
            return redirect('/home');
        } else {
            //Otherwise redirect back to login page with errors.
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors('Invalid email  or password');
        }
        //If the user didn't check the remember me checkbox then don't remember him.
    } else {
        if (\Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            $user = User::findOrFail($email);
            \Auth::login($user);
            return redirect('/home');
        } else {
            //Otherwise redirect back to login page with errors.
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors('Invalid email or password');
        }
    }
}
```

instead of redirecting to /home laravel redirects to /user/login (which is the POST route that is used to log users in) user is logged in and redirected to this page and gets a 404 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok so apparently the fix was to use `redirect()->intended('home')` instead of the regular `redirect('home')`